# How do I mimic Hibernate hbm2ddl "create" behaviour in Liquibase?

Tags: java, maven-2, jakarta-ee, hbm2ddl, liquibase

I've worked with liquibase 1.9.5 for a while now and got it to replace hibernate hbm2ddl strategy of creating tables and loading fixtures in it. Since it's a maven project and since I use hsqldb (using file create=true), I simply create the db in the target folder so that I have a fresh database anytime I test the application. Works fine till that I realize:

**1**  I will need the database to be recreated when doing integration test using mysql database now

**2** I will definitely need the same solution for a non maven project.

So basically how do I drop and create the database when using liquibase as opposed to hbm2ddl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to add a separate database call before liquibase update that runs the sql

```
DROP DATABASE X;
CREATE DATABASE X
```

Liquibase does have a dropAll command which can be used to drop everything in a schema, but it is slower than drop/create database on mysql and may miss some database objects.

Comment: Hi nathan thanks for reading and providing a solution.By the way can liquibase work with jpa implementation of hibernate in a sense that it can create the schema based on my domain model? (hoping this is not too much to ask ;) )

Comment: Not currently. There is a patch propsed at http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/jpa-persistance-xml which has not been integrated yet, although you could make the change locally and see how it works.